# Cannot update Google Chrome portable

Tags: google-chrome, updates

It said that update server is not available when I hit about google chrome in the options. What do I do?

Comment: which OS is it ?

Answer (score 3):

With regard to paubbessley's answer - it appears then that Google Chrome Portable can't be updated with the About Google Chrome update feature.  I have also noticed this and I consider this a bug in Google Chrome Portable.  Google Chrome should be able to detect the difference between a "regular full install" and a the "portable" version and allow the user to properly update the Portable version as well straight into the same directory that they are running Google Chrome Portable from.  Right now I have to manually download and install the latest version of Google Chrome Portable Beta from SourceForge.  This is a nuisance and is a bug in my book.  I have suggested that the developers fix this issue in the Google Forum.

Comment: 5 years have passed and I am facing this issue cant find solution. Didnt they still fix it?

Comment: Issue remains exactly the same as reported and replied to 5 years ago.  Google does not appear to be interested in fixing this issue (bug).  Manual downloads and installs via SourceForge still work for Google Chrome Portable.

Comment: Issue still remains today albeit I just manually update now from the one of the portable apps sites.  Contrary to what Google says in the Error 1 description, Chrome Portable may indeed be upgraded right on top of the existing portable directory without any problems whatsoever.  I have done this for years now with absolutely no side effects.  You just need to have Chrome closed prior to the actual update.

Comment: Issue still remains for 10+ years, the bug is still here.
Asked question - how to retain settings. Will try John C's method from comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Can be more specific about the error number that you are seeing  ? [Google Chrome help lists](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=111996)  different variations of "Update server not available"

> **Update server not available (error: 1)**
>
> Error 1 means that Google Chrome can't
>   be upgraded in its current directory.
>
> **Update server not available (error: 3)**
>
> Error 3 is a failure to communicate
>   with Google Update. There are two
>   known reasons for this:
>
> You're running Vista and you have
>   configured Google Chrome to always run
>   as administrator. This is a known
>   issue with the Google Chrome
>   auto-updating mechanism and can be
>   avoided by simply running Google
>   Chrome as a normal user. Additionally,
>   keep in mind that for security reasons
>   we recommend that you don't elevate
>   the privilege of Google Chrome to
>   administrator.
>
> Google Update isn't registered
>   properly. To fix this, verify that
>   GoogleUpdate.exe exists in the
>   location specified in the Windows
>   Registry Editor.
>
> **Update server not available (error: 7)**
>
> Error 7 means the update was
>   downloaded successfully, but it failed
>   to install properly.
>
> Try restarting your computer. Then
>   check your Windows Task Manager and
>   see if GoogleUpdate.exe appears in the
>   list of processes. If it does, try
>   updating again through the browser
>   again. If you're still encountering
>   problems, try reinstalling Google
>   Chrome from
>   http://www.google.com/chrome
>
> If that still doesn't fix the problem,
>   help us investigate by reporting the
>   problem.
>
> **Checking for update never completes**
>
> If you see the message "Checking for
>   updates" and a little icon that spins
>   forever, it means that Google Update
>   was unable to communicate with Google
>   Chrome. Make sure that you are using
>   the latest version of Google Chrome,
>   available at
>   http://www.google.com/chrome

Comment: I see error 1, my version of portable chrome is: 4.0.249.30

Answer (score 1):

The portable version of Chrome is not upgradeable because its directory structure is different to that of the regular, installed Chrome. The application can detect the difference and halts the update process - this would fit with the error code of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Why not download the latest standalone version of Google Chrome [here](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1)? If you're worried about settings and bookmarks; Google Chrome can sync between versions of GC you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the version from PortableApps, you can simply download the latest version and install it to the PARENT of the folder that contains it, this will upgrade. Doing this will keep all settings including add-ins, history, etc.

@Wollen Muts: The reason for not using the Google Standalone version will be that it will not install without at least local admin rights. Not everyone has this capability on corporate PC's.