# How to fix Chrome Portable settings

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, history, cookies, setup

Once in a while my Chrome Portable v72 on a start pretend it forgot history, cookies, bookmarks, everything, and don't let to update itself.

This is a known problem with 10+ years history with Chrome, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/135735/cannot-update-google-chrome-portable)

But sqlite files in **<install_path>\Data\profile\Default**

```
Bookmarks
Cookies
History
History Provider Cache
Login Data
etc
```

are present in profile folder and workable, can be accessed in db tools.

But just copying them to corresponding folder in latest available version, 88, doesn't help.

There should be, I believe, some setting to make Chrome use them.

After all, Chrome seems to be unable import settings from previous installs.

How to recover the state of Chrome to be used in (other version) fresh Crome portable install?

Answer (score 0):

If you sign into google, everything will sync. Your bookmarks, your wallpapers, your settings will all sync. Sign in on the google chrome you have everything under then sign in under the other google chrome and it will load all your stuff. This way, even if you completely reset your computer or something you will still have all your data!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is rather about fixing a bit broken config of a browser copy. After all, this is not the best practice to sync, I believe.